# Why do I get AttributeError when trying to open a folder in django cms filer manager?

Tags: django, amazon-s3, django-cms, django-filer

I have a fresh install of django cms and when I try to create a folder and add images to it using the filer app it just gives me the error:

AttributeError at /en/admin/filer/folder/1/list/
'str' object has no attribute '_meta'

it looks like the issue is in filer/admin/folderadmin.py in directory_listing

I thought maybe it had something to do with the fact that I was using django-storage to store on s3, but I took that part out so that it just stored the files locally and I am still getting the error. If anyone has any information on how to fix this please let me know. This is happening out of the box with no previous data.

Comment: Which django & django CMS version are you using?

Comment: I think it may have been an orphaned plugin issue. I ran the command "python manage.py cms delete-orphaned-plugins" and the issue went away.

Comment: Django==1.9
django-cms==3.4.4